# Extending Pig SUM function

Tags: apache-pig

The built in Pig SUM eval function returns null if the bag is empty . How can I override this(as simple as possible ) to return 0 instead of null .

```
  public class CustomSum extends SUM{
   // Which methods to override.
 }
```

Or Is there any way I can do it in script to check if SUM returned null then make it 0.

Eg : A = FOREACH (COGROUP OUTER) group as url , (1-$d)+$d*SUM(a.values) as totalValue .

I am doing a outer COGROUP . So there are some records in the group which doesn’t have values and in that case I would like to return constant(1-$d) . However as SUM returns null , totalValues is becoming null.

Answer (score 0):

You can use if else logic here. If the SUM causes a null value and you want that to be zero,  return the (1-$d), else return the entire sum.

`A = FOREACH (COGROUP OUTER) 
     GENERATE group as url , 
     (1-$d)+$d*SUM(a.values)==null?(1-$d):(1-$d)+$d*SUM(a.values) as totalValue`